# Static files not being served to sub-directories in Node.js using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to serve static files to the following URL and for some reason, when I access this path: "http://www.domain.com/tut-view/1" - it gives me the the following error:

```
*GET http://www.domain.com/tut-view/javascripts/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)*
```

It is looking for the static files starting from that folder itself. I don't know why.

This is the app configuration code.

```
// configure Express
app.configure(function() {
  // More app configurations above ^
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

This works - it serves all the static CSS and JavaScript files:

```
app.get('/tut-view', function (req, res) {
  res.render('tut-view', {});
});
```

This doesn't work - It gives me the error above:

```
app.get('/tut-view/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.render('tut-view', {});
});
```

I am guessing it is because the path is pointing to the inside of another folder. Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative paths for static assets, something like this: `../javascripts/jquery.js`, so from `/tut-view` it resolves to `/javascripts/jquery.js` and from `/tut-view/1` it resolves to `/tut-view/javascripts/jquery.js`, which is a wrong path. You should use absolute path: `/javascripts/jquery.js`